# Highlighting point in geom_point with different categories in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets say I'm doing the following graph:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris$Species, y=iris$Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species))
```

But then I want to highlight a very specific point (or points), in its specific category.
For example, the fourth sample in  Iris.

I tried:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris$Species, y=iris$Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species)) +
  geom_point(iris[4,], aes(x=iris$Species, y=iris$Petal.Length), 
             colour = "black", size = 5)
```

Which gives me

> Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

How can I highlight a specific point?

Comment: Try `geom_point(data = iris[4,], ..)`. The first argument of the geoms is the mapping.

Comment: ... and please use `aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)`. Otherwsie you get an error too.

Comment: Try this: `ggplot(iris , aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species)) +
  geom_point(data=iris[4,], aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length))
`